# JWplayer with Apple FairPlay DRM Implementation

Tags: ios, swift3, jwplayer, fairplay

I am using this demo:
[jwplayer/jwplayer-ios-bestPracticeApps](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-ios-bestPracticeApps/tree/master/JWBestPracticeApps/JWFairPlayDrm)

After calling self.player.load(encryptedFile) , The callback functions fetchAppIdentifier, fetchContentIdentifier and fetchContentKey should be called after the player determines that the video is DRM protected, however none of the functions are called.

Any idea would be helpful, and by the way are there any other demo available? this is the only one I could find.

Thank you :)

Comment: It is because it failed to load http. You need to add AppTransport Security in .plist file
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Comment: I know this is very old, but did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem!